# Laravel 5.4, changing login to work from header

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5.4

For my own project I am needing login/registering functions. But I don't to use the standard Laravel login pages and such. I want to use the Login form I have in my header. But I can't seem to figure out how to make the Controller use the login information from my header form and handle it in the desired way.

My login form is an include in my header and the code is as following:

```
<li class="single-icon nk-drop-item">
<a href="" class="no-link-effect">
    <span class="fa fa-sign-in"></span>
</a>
<div class="dropdown">
    <div class="nk-sign-form">
        <div class="nk-sign-form-container">

            <!-- START: Login Form -->
            <form class="nk-sign-form-login active" action="{{ url('/') }}">
                {{ csrf_field() }}
                <h4>Log In</h4>

                <input class="form-control " type="text" placeholder="Username" id="username"  name="username" value="{{ old('username') }}" required autofocus>
                <div class="nk-gap"></div>

                <input class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Password" id="password"  name="password" required>
                <div class="nk-gap"></div>

                <div class="form-check pull-left">
                    <label class="form-check-label">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input"> Remember Me
                    </label>
                </div>
                <button class="nk-btn nk-btn-color-white text-dark-1 pull-right">Log In</button>

                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <div class="nk-gap"></div>
                <div class="text-right">
                    <a class="nk-sign-form-register-toggle" href="#">Register</a> |
                    <a class="nk-sign-form-lost-toggle" href="#">Lost Password?</a>
                </div>
            </form>
            <!-- END: Login Form -->

            <!-- START: Lost Password Form -->
            <form class="nk-sign-form-lost" action="#">
                <h4>Lost Password</h4>

                <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Username or Email">
                <div class="nk-gap"></div>

                <button class="nk-btn nk-btn-color-white text-dark-1 pull-right">Get New Password</button>

                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <div class="nk-gap"></div>
                <a class="nk-sign-form-login-toggle pull-right" href="#">Back to Log In</a>
            </form>
            <!-- END: Lost Password Form -->

            <!-- START: Register Form -->
            <form class="nk-sign-form-register" action="#">
                <h4>Register</h4>

                <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Username">
                <div class="nk-gap"></div>

                <input class="form-control" type="email" placeholder="Email">
                <div class="nk-gap"></div>

                <div>A password will be emailed to you.</div>
                <div class="nk-gap"></div>

                <button class="nk-btn nk-btn-color-white text-dark-1 pull-right">Register</button>

                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <div class="nk-gap"></div>
                <a class="nk-sign-form-login-toggle pull-right" href="#">Back to Log In</a>
            </form>
            <!-- END: Register Form -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My LoginController is as following:

```
    namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{


    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    public function username()
    {
        return 'username';
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'login' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required'
        ];
    }


}
```

If someone could help me in the way of pointing me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated. If I need to post some more code I'll be happy to. Thanks in advance 
**edit: I've uploaded the code to the domain: [verenmanta.site](https://verenmanta.site), you can view the header and login form over there if that may help!**

Comment: In Login form action just mention `route('login')` same for Register form `route('register')`

Comment: Thanks for your response! But when I do that I get redirected to the standard lLravel login page, which I altered to the login file mentioned above. No login notification or other redirect.

Comment: I see you haven't mention method for `form` so by default it is taking `GET` which may cause unable to login & redirection to login page. Try with `POST`

Comment: You sir are amazing. I had in fact forgotten the post method. After that an correcting the Authenticate redirect everything worked as a charm!